# Jasmine with Express - testing for response redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

My controller action:

```
//...

this.create = function (req, res) {
   return res.redirect('http://www.example.com');
}

//..
```

Using Jasmine how can I assert that the action redirects to `http://www.example.com`? Should I supply a mock `res` in order to perform assertions on it using Jasmine spies?

Answer (score 0):

So, one way to test is

`expect(response.request.href).toContain("redirected");`

However, this actually navigates to the endpoint, so if you want to test an absolute url, you actually navigate to that endpoint, and therefore you are subject to any additional redirects and/or internet issues